# How do I change a variable while using a function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, p5.js

I'm coding on the p5.js Website Editor
So I'm trying to make a lot of rectangles that move when I press a specific key.
To make that I thought of making a function where I would put everything related to the rectangles moving, so that I don't have to rewrite a code to make them move every time. I want all of them to move the same way.

This is what I tried

```
function wall(x, y, sx, sy){
  rect(x, y, sx, sy);
  if(keyIsDown(65)){
     return x+1;
     }
}
    wall(300, 300, 20, 30);
```

and just got a rectangle in the right coordinates but not moving when I press the "a" key

Comment: It returns `x+1`, you need to assign that to the variable that you use in the next call.

Comment: Where and how often is “wall” called? At the minute, you have a key code listener but only when it’s in the actually wall function.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker I am trying to make at least 30 different walls that all move according to what key I am pressing. So it's called a lot of times and the key can be pressed at anytime

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. This tiny fragment doesn't offer much to work with in order to actually write an answer.

Comment: @RiceAndCheese - but how is wall being called? Is it in a loop? Is it called x amount of times a second? In your example, it is only ever called once. You do nothing with the value returned. Currently based on your code example, nothing will ever happen because your key listener is inside a wall function that is called and ran only once.

Comment: You expect that code to be called when you press a key? Where is this event handler being bound?

Comment: @scottdavidwalker - I see what you mean. So the "If" statement should be in a loop in order that the rectangles move (for example) 20 times a second, right? And yes, I will be calling the wall function more than once.

Comment: @epascarello - I do not want the function to be called when I press a key, I want the x or y of the rectangles created by this function to move when I press the key.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to move things in p5.js, you need to use the `draw()` function. The `draw()` function runs the code inside of it repeatedly multiple times a second. You can use that to create an illusion of movement by updating the location of your object by a small amount every frame and then re-rendering the object.

I don't see you using the `draw()` function, so I'm guessing this is the first part of your problem.

The second part I see is that you are referring to "a lot of rectangles", but you are only making one.

Consider the code below for a quick solution (copy-paste it into the p5.js editor to see it in action).

```
let wallX = 200;
let wallY = 100;
let wallSpeed = 2;
let wallWidth = 20;
let wallHeight = 30;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    wallX = wallX - wallSpeed;
  } else if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    wallX = wallX + wallSpeed;
  }

  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    wallY = wallY - wallSpeed;
  } else if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    wallY = wallY + wallSpeed;
  }

  wall(wallX, wallY, wallWidth, wallHeight);
}

function wall(x, y, sx, sy) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    rect(x, y + sy * i, sx, sy);
  }
}
```

In this code snippet, I am defining some global variables (generally not a good practice, but for the purposes of a p5.js sketch this is fine). The important ones are the `wallX` and the `wallY` variables. These variables are defined outside of the `draw()` function, so they will not be reset every time the loop runs.

Inside the loop, there are key handlers defined (I used the arrow keys for clarity). If the arrow keys are pressed, the position of the wall will change by the `wallSpeed` value per frame.

Also, note the `background(220)` call - this redraws the grey background at the beginning of the loop. If you remove that, the results of the previous renders will be visible, chances are that you don't want that.

Finally, the `wall()` function. You can see that the key press handling is not done inside of it - it needs the state information to come from the outside. All this function does is use a loop to draw five rectangles in a stack, at the position it is given. When the position changes, it redraws the wall in a different place on the canvas. The rectangles all refer to the root x and y values, so they will all move together as a unit.

Another way would be to create the class to represent a Wall and make instances of that class and call methods on those instances, but that could be something to revisit once you gain more experience with p5.js.

Hope this helps!